# Replication between Mysql and Postgres for data warehousing

Tags: mysql, postgresql, replication

Context: my DBA has written scripts to delta load data from a Mysql slave we have of our main OLTP to our Postgres DWH staging DB. He's leaving and I want to find a more sustainable way to handle this.

**So I was thinking of setting up a master-slave replication between both.**

Some posts over the internet are covering this topic (database independent replicaton), but they all look obsolete and using solutions that are in arrested development.

The only viable option to us seems to be SymetricDS.
Have you heard of this used in BI?
Is it reasonable to get into this if you're not a dev?
Is it a lot of maintenance? What about the perf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the people interested:
After testing, I came to the conclusion that SymmetricDS is not a sustainable enough solution, especially for BI implementations in SMEs with relatively scarce HR resources.

I've decided to mimic the  replication process myself with a super dynamic python script running everything 15min, and some optimization on the mysql slave (completely independent from the master).

It works just fine, and is way lighter than the aforementioned option.

Cheers,
V.